# To Remove Enter marks (\n) in Lua

Tags: luatex, automation, lua

[image]I have using `LuaLaTeX Version : 1.12.0` and i have converting `XML to LaTeX` using Lua Script.

I have need to remove enter marks in Lua Scripts. How to achieve this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Classical and Quantum Gravity}
\author{Author Here}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I have tried many ways in `Lua`. My Lua Code is:

```
TeXIn=string.gsub(TeXIn,[[\n]],[[]])
TeXIn=string.gsub(TeXIn,[[\string\n]],[[]])
TeXIn=string.gsub(TeXIn,[[\n\string]],[[]])
TeXIn=string.gsub(TeXIn,[[\string\n\string]],[[]])
TeXIn=string.gsub(TeXIn,[[\par]],[[]])
io.write(TeXIn) -- for display the text in terminal/command prompt
tex.sprint(TeXIn) -- for print the text and view in PDF
```

`tex.tprint` is not working.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: please post the code in a way that can be tested and show how you are calling it. As you use tex.sprint you must be calling this from luatex not from  a standalone Lua script, but how are you calling it? It affects how much quotting is needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Instead of `tex.sprint` any other way we can print the text in PDF? Like `io.print` is not working but `io.write` is printing the text in terminal.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: No, each newlines i have got ? with box in the PDF. This is my main problem. But when i have run `LuaLaTeX filename.tex` it's working fine. When i have used my Lua Script (for converting XML to LaTeX) it's showing ? in the PDF. The Source code is many more lines for conversion `XML to LaTeX`.

Comment: as I say you need to clarify your question to show what you are doing. If you get ? typeset output it is highly unlikely to be from newlines in the source so removing them will make no difference, but it is impossible to guess what input you are using and how you are applying the lua.

Comment: @David: i have used `tex.write(TeXIn)` and image is updated in the questions.

Comment: you should provide a single  tex file that uses the input shown and the lua shown and produces output with ?.  So far all we know is that you have a document that you have not shown and some processing that you have not shown and it has some unexpected ?in the output. There is no help that can be given. Show the output _of the code in the question_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you want to print the entire document in a semi-verbatim style as one long line wrapped string

so if `z1z.tex` is

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Classical and Quantum Gravity}
\author{Author Here}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

and `z1z.lua` is

```
local f = assert(io.open("z1z.tex", "rb"))
local TeXIn = f:read("*all")
f:close()


tex.sprint(TeXIn)
```

then these can be combined with the luatex document

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\zz#1{{%
\catcode10=10 % control-j is space
\catcode`\\=12 % verbatimish output
\catcode`\{=12 % verbatimish output
\catcode`\}=12 % verbatimish output
\ttfamily    % monospace
\directlua{dofile('#1')}
}}

\zz{z1z.lua}

\end{document}
```

which produces the result

[image]

The Lua here is doing nothing other than inputting the file, but perhaps in your real use case, it may play a role.